# Displaying a "friendly name" for an ID in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace-for-business

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets which contains information split across several sheets. To keep things consistent between sheets, I use numbers as IDs, like (very simplified example):

- Users: User ID, Name, Address,
- Products: Product ID, Product Name
- Orders: Order ID, User ID, Product ID

This works fine, but the "orders" sheet is hard to read at a glance and hard to add new items to because it's just a random list of numbers. What I'd like is to have a more user-friendly interface on top of the data, so that the orders table shows something more like "Order ID, User Name, Product Name" so that it's easy to read and I can add a row by just knowing the names, without having to look up the correct IDs.

What I want is for under the hood it to *store* the actual IDs so the table doesn't break if we e.g. rename a product. Is there a good pattern for accomplishing this in Sheets?

Research: I've confirmed this is possible to accomplish just using the various `LOOKUP` functions, but then the cell contents are `=LOOKUP(NAME)`, not the actual ID, which means they will break if the name changes.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. What do you mean by "under the hood" in the Google Sheets context? Have you considered to use Google Apps Script to extend Google Sheets? Also, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: _a good pattern for accomplishing this in Sheets?_ IMO, yes but not business-as-usual. You want to select the Product Name but save the ID to the Orders sheet. To do this, I think you're likely to have a specific-purpose sheet for creating Orders, you'll have a `dropdown` to select the Product Name (maybe for User Name too), `vlookup` (or `index/match`) will get the Product ID, you'll trigger a "save/update" script, and the Order ID, User ID, Product ID will be appended to the "Orders" sheet. Does that sound the sort of thing that you expected? Of course, others might have a different view.

Comment: Added some description of research efforts.

Yeah, I think a "save" button that converts looked-up IDs to stored IDs is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is normalised, but you'd like to create new orders by selecting the Product Name and User Name, even though these fields are not part of the Orders" table.

There are many possible solutions to your question; this is just one example.

---

1. Create a sheet for Building Orders. The screenshot below shows just a single order, but this could be adapted to create multiple orders in one sitting. In addition, that layout is just an example and can be changed to suit the users needs.
2. Use `Data validation` to populate the cells for Product Name and User Name. Make the respective ranges bigger than the existing data so that additional Products and Users will be automatically added to the dropdown list.
3. Formula for User ID and Product ID:

   - User ID: `=if(isblank(B4),"",lookup(B4,Users!B2:B,Users!A2:A))`
   - Product ID = `=if(isblank(B3),"",lookup(B3,Products!B2:B,Products!A2:A))`
4. the Order ID is a calculated field. In this example, it is assumed that the value is "one plus the last Order#". Other variations could be catered for. In Cell B8 and B9, two alternatives are shown for calculating the last Order ID on the Orders Sheet.
5. When the script is executed, the data in the range "D3:F3" is updated to "Orders", and then the data on the build form is cleared - ready for the next order.
6. This script is executed manually. However there are many examples available for executing a script based on a button or drawing.

---

**Orders Builder (Blank)**

[image: screenshot]

---

**Orders Builder (Populated)**

### [image]

```
 function wa14609501() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ordersmaster = "Orders";
  var ordersbuild = "Orders_Build";
  
  var ord = ss.getSheetByName(ordersmaster);
  var ordbuild = ss.getSheetByName(ordersbuild);

  // get the order details from the Build sheet
  var range = ordbuild.getRange("D3:F3");
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  // get the last row from the Orders sheet
  var OrdersLR = ord.getLastRow();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row = "+OrdersLR);
  
// update the Order to Orders
  var newOrder = ord.getRange(+OrdersLR+1,1,1,3).setValues(values)
  
  // clear the order information
  var newordrange = ordbuild.getRange("B3:B4").clearContent();
  
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, very detailed!